# Finding how many lattice points are on the line between two given points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I know the slope is $\frac{303-28}{459-34}=\frac{275}{425}=\frac{11}{17}$ this is an irrational number so there are either no lattice points or one lattice point.

I was looking at [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/background/countingLecture/lines/lines/index.php) link to try and get some more information on how to solve this.

So it says that if you have $y=ax+b$ where $a$ is irrational and $b$ is rational, then you have one lattice point. So the equation of this line is $y=\frac{11}{17}x+b$

$28=\frac{11}{17}(34)+b$

$y=\frac{11}{17}x+6$

So there is only one lattice point, is this correct?

Comment: 11/17 is rational, because it is the *ratio* of two integers.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

You're starting on a lattice point (both coordinates are integers). Where do you land if you go up $11$ spaces and right $17$ spaces?

Rinse and repeat until you run out of line segment.

A couple of follow-on questions:

- You can find the answer "brute force" by doing what I've outlined. Once you get that answer, calculate $(303-28)/11$ and $(459-34)/17$. How does the answer you got compare with these? What's the connection?
- Also, you calculated the slope to be $11/17$. Why is it important that the slope be expressed in lowest terms when you use it to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: thank you, i made a mistake about the rational slope. for $(303-28)/11=25$ and same for $(459-34)/17$. so does this mean there are 25 points in between that are lattice points?

Comment: Not quite. Try the same problem using endpoints $(2,2)$ and $(27,12)$. The slope is $2/5$. (This is one that's easy to draw on graph paper.) Write down all of the lattice points on the line segment, and throw out the two endpoints. Calculate $(27-2)/5$ and compare.

Comment: @john sorry but I'm still not understanding. even if the slope is 2/5, i don't know how to find the lattice points.

Comment: Start on $(2,2)$. Go up $2$ and over $5$; you get to $(7,4)$. Do it again and you get to $(12,6)$. And so on ...